# How can i make divs next to other but keep them in place like in screenshot

Tags: html, css

as i explained everything in title then i will just provide you guys with code i have for now, i've been trying to reach what i want for so long but no luck....
It is acting like responsive but i want to keep it in place even it's resized...
Screenshot[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Home
        </title>

        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
                padding: 20px 50px 150px;
                margin: 0 0 0 0;
                font-size: 13px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #content1{
                //float: left;
                width: 300px;
                height: 740px;
                margin-left: 50px;
            }
            #content2{
                //float: right;
                margin-right: 50px;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            #content3{
                width: 740px;
                height: 740px;
            }
            .content{
                margin: 20px 100px auto auto;
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: #F0F0F0;
            }
            #navbar{
                margin: 10px auto auto auto;
                min-width: 120px;
                min-height: 120px;
            }
            #navbar-menu{

            }
            #navbar-menu ul {
                text-align: left;
                display: inline;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
                list-style: none;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
            }
            #navbar-menu ul li {
                font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: -4px;
                position: relative;
                padding: 15px 20px;
                background: #fff;
                cursor: pointer;
                -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
                -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
                -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
                -o-transition: all 0.2s;
                transition: all 0.2s;
            }
            #navbar-menu ul li:hover {
                background: #555;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #navbar-menu ul li ul {
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 48px;
                left: 0;
                width: 150px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                -moz-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
                display: none;
                opacity: 0;
                visibility: hidden;
                -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
                -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
                -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
                -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
                -transition: opacity 0.2s;
            }
            #navbar-menu ul li ul li { 
                background: #555; 
                display: block; 
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
            }
            #navbar-menu ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
            #navbar-menu ul li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            #navbar-menu ul li.active {
                background: #555;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body background="../images/bg.png">
        <div id="navbar">
            <div id="navbar-menu">
                <ul><li class="active">Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>
                    Projects
                    <ul>
                        <li>Web Design</li>
                        <li>Web Development</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content1" class="content">
        <h1>ey</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content2" class="content">
        <h2>eye</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content3" class="content">
        <h3>eyey</h3>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what specifically is your problem?

Comment: ...and what screenshot?

Comment: give width of each div in `%`

Comment: If you want it to not be responsive, put your 3 divs inside another div with fixed witdth (1440px). It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified some of your CSS code:

**CSS : Updated**

```
#content1{
    width: 20%;
    height: 740px;  
}
#content2{
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
}
#content3{
    width: 40%;
    height: 740px;
}
.content{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:5%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
```

Replace the above code to your Style.

Comment: Thanks for trying but divs still jumping down when zooming.

Comment: @XeJuicY Sorry i misunderstood you, check the update now, if still any issue feel free to ask.

Comment: So is the answer appropriate?

Comment: Yes, you are my hero :D Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad that it worked for you, request you to accept the answer or at least upvote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Answer accepted BUT can't upvote (sorry) it says i need reputation level 15.

Comment: It's fine, no issue buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for a media Query. Such as

@media (min width: 540px) {
     "div you want to adjust {
        "property you want to affect"
  }
}

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Well _i just want it **to not be "responsive"* like the divs keep jumping down when i resize... i want them fix.**

Comment: Sorry, I misread you there, thought you wanted responsive. I think it's been mentioned but you will need to convert px widths to % with some basic math.

Comment: Well, then i do not know how can i achieve that ... My friend has the thing i want on his website http://nospvp.8u.cz

Comment: Try setting content 1 and 2 width to 20% and content 3 to 40%. this will leave you with 10% for the left and right margins totaling up to 100%.